# Power Series Approximation of ln(x)

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I am working on building a small embedded calculator, and am working on adding a natural logarithm function that utilizes only + and -.

I have worked out the power series representation of ln(x) as 
 $\ \frac {-\Sigma (-1)^n * (x-a)^n} n $

This summation only converges however if $ |x| < 1$

What can I do to approximate larger values of X?

Comment: What you wrote is a formula for $\ln(1+x-a)$ (By the way, you want the division by $n$ to be inside the sum).

If you want to approximate $\ln(x)$ around $x=a$, then you first write 

$$\ln(x)=\ln(x+a-a)=\ln(a(1+(x-a)/a)=\ln a+\ln(1+(x-a)/a)$$ 

and then apply your formula to get $$\ln a+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(x-a)^n}{a^n n}$$.

Notice that this approximation requires that you know $\ln a$. 

Anyway, this will always have a finite convergence radius, because logarithm has a divergence at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hold the value for $\ln2$, then you can reduce every input $x$ by multiplying or dividing by 2 so that the result $y=2^{-m}x$ is inside the interval $[\frac23,\frac43]$. To that you then apply the series
$$
\ln(1+(y-1))=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}·(y-1)^n
$$
and
$$
\ln x=m·\ln2+\ln(1+(y-1))
$$

Answer (score 0):

We restrict to $x$ positive, so if $|x|<1$ does not hold, then either $x=1$, $x>1$. For $x=1$, the computation is trivial (just hardwire it), for $x>1$, $1/x$ is small. So compute it for $1/x$ and then you know how to relate that to $ln(x)$.